# how to run chromedp in docker

Tags: docker, chromedp

I am trying to run [chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp) in docker.
My [main.go](https://github.com/ypapax/chromedp_docker/blob/master/main.go):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Llongfile)
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(
        context.Background(),
        chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf),
    )
    defer cancel()

    // create a timeout
    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, 15 * time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    u := `https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent`
    selector := `#detected_value`
    log.Println("requesting", u)
    log.Println("selector", selector)
    var result string
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate(u),
        chromedp.WaitReady(selector),
        chromedp.OuterHTML(selector, &result),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("result:\n%s", result)
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest as build-env
RUN mkdir $GOPATH/src/app
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/app
ENV GO111MODULE=on
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
COPY main.go .
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o /root/app

FROM chromedp/headless-shell
COPY --from=build-env /root/app /
CMD ["/app"]
```

When I run it:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

It outputs:

```
app_1  | [1129/192523.576726:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
app_1  | [1129/192523.602779:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
app_1  | 
app_1  | DevTools listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9222/devtools/browser/3fa247e0-e2fa-484e-8b5f-172b392701bb
app_1  | [1129/192523.836854:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
app_1  | [1129/192523.838804:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
app_1  | [1129/192523.845866:ERROR:egl_util.cc(60)] Failed to load GLES library: /headless-shell/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: /headless-shell/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
app_1  | [1129/192523.871796:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(176)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
app_1  | [1129/192523.897083:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1220)] The GPU process has crashed 1 time(s)
app_1  | [1129/192523.926741:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
app_1  | [1129/192523.930111:ERROR:egl_util.cc(60)] Failed to load GLES library: /headless-shell/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: /headless-shell/swiftshader/libGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
app_1  | [1129/192523.943794:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(176)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
app_1  | [1129/192523.948757:WARNING:gpu_process_host.cc(1220)] The GPU process has crashed 2 time(s)
app_1  | [1129/192523.950107:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(138)] Failed to launch GPU process.
app_1  | [1129/192524.013014:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(138)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

So it doesn't run my go app. I expect that `chromedp/headless-shell` contains google-chrome and my golang app would successfully use it over [github.com/chromedp/chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp)

## Update 1

I [added](https://github.com/ypapax/chromedp_docker/commit/9090630014ab408ab80624be2ea66127ce3b6312#diff-3254677a7917c6c01f55212f86c57fbfR13) missing directories:

```
RUN mkdir -p /headless-shell/swiftshader/ \
    && cd /headless-shell/swiftshader/ \
    && ln -s ../libEGL.so libEGL.so \
    && ln -s ../libGLESv2.so libGLESv2.so
```

and now have the following output, my app still not running:

```
app_1  | [1202/071210.095414:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
app_1  | [1202/071210.112632:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
app_1  | 
app_1  | DevTools listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9222/devtools/browser/86e31db1-3a17-4da6-9e2f-696647572492
app_1  | [1202/071210.166158:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
app_1  | [1202/071210.186307:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(426)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
```

## Update 2

Looks like `CMD ["/app"]` doesn't run my main.go file because it doesn't print any lines from it.
And when I run it manually:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/docker exec -ti chromedp_docker_app_1 /bin/bash

root@0c417fd159a2:/# /app
2019/12/02 07:40:34 app is running
2019/12/02 07:40:34 /go/src/app/main.go:26: requesting https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent
2019/12/02 07:40:34 /go/src/app/main.go:27: selector #detected_value
2019/12/02 07:40:34 /go/src/app/main.go:35: exec: "google-chrome": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I see that `google-chrome` app is still not there, hmmm....

Comment: did you find the solution?  I have the same problem. @arspreet answer did not help me

Comment: @big-toni Did you find the solution? I have the same problem and arspreet answer did not help me.

Answer (score 11):

You are missing few things here, First you need to run google-headless-chrome inside your container. you can use following Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.12.0-alpine3.9

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache bash git && apk add --no-cache chromium

# Installs latest Chromium package.
RUN echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    harfbuzz@edge \
    nss@edge \
    freetype@edge \
    ttf-freefont@edge \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/* \
    && mkdir /var/cache/apk

RUN go get github.com/mafredri/cdp


CMD chromium-browser --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-web-security --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --disable-sync --disable-default-apps --hide-scrollbars --metrics-recording-only --mute-audio --no-first-run --no-sandbox
```

I am using CDP, More robust and fun for me!
This is the link for CDP: https://github.com/mafredri/cdp

Answer (score 1):

Is not pretty but here is a simple docker that worked for me

```
FROM golang:1.16.5 AS build-env

RUN apt update && apt -y upgrade 

RUN apt -y install chromium

WORKDIR /app


ADD ./ ./

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o /docker-gs-ping

CMD [ "/docker-gs-ping" ]
```